# Updating App layout design to users without submit to update in Firebase config?

Tags: android, firebase, android-studio, android-layout, firebase-realtime-database

I want to update design of my Android app layout to users but the question is how can i release my new layout to users without submit update in app store. I browse in web I see results like Firebase Config, There is a chance to release new
Layout to users using firebase config?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This entirely depends on how you have coded your Android app, but my bet is that you are using native code and so you would have to roll out a new version of the app through the stores since the layout would require a new "binary".

There are ways to code so that your app is "meta-data driven" allowing you to send layout configuration as **data** rather than **code**, but you either have to code for that or leverage a technology already designed for that.

Web technologies allow for exactly this.  The browser (or in the case of React Native, the RN engine) receives layout data as HTML, Javascript and CSS.  Updates to the UI involves simply updating the HTML on the webserver hosting it, the existing "app" on the phone does not need to be modified as it is an "engine" that download configuration data "on the fly".  In the case of the Expo framework (https://expo.io/), it is React Native that supports [Over The Air Updates](https://docs.expo.io/guides/configuring-ota-updates/).

There are other frameworks and coding approaches that you can leverage to support Over The Air updates.

Note: though you might use various features of Firebase to enable OTA, there is nothing specific to Firebase regarding OTA that I'm aware of.